# Access outer attribute from a function override

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a wrapper class which redefines a method of the wrapped class. Is there any way the wrapper's state can be accessed from inside the override method?

```
class WidgetWrapper

  attr_accessor :result_saved_by_widget

  def initialize(widget)
    @widget = widget
    # we intercept the widget's usual "save" method so we can see
    # what the widget tries to save
    def @widget.save_result(result) # this override works fine ...
      OUTER.result_saved_by_widget = result # .. but I need something like this inside it!
    end
  end

  def call
    widget.calculate # this will call "save_result" at some stage
  end

end

# How it gets used
wrapper = Wrapper.new(Widget.new)
wrapper.call
puts wrapper.result_saved_by_widget
```

Comment: What's do you want to access with `OUTER`, again?

Comment: The wrapper. Solved it now anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, I would [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-extend) the object with a module:

```
module WidgetExtension
  attr_accessor :results_saved_by_widget

  def save_result(result)
    @results_saved_by_widget = result
    super
  end
end


w = Widget.new
w.extend(WidgetExtension)
w.calculate

w.results_saved_by_widget #=> stored value
```

Comment: I worry a bit about breaking Liskov Sub Principle like this, but seems any way you do it is going to be a hack and this is certainly a straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with a perfectly stupid hack - injecting the wrapper object beforehand, using instance_variable_set.

```
class WidgetWrapper

  attr_accessor :result_saved_by_widget

  def initialize(widget)
    @widget = widget
    @widget.instance_variable_set :@wrapper, self
    # we intercept the widget's usual "save" method so we can see
    # what the widget tries to save
    def @widget.save_result(result) # this override works fine ...
      @wrapper.result_saved_by_widget = result # ... and this works too :)
    end
  end

  def call
    widget.calculate # this will call "save_result" at some stage
  end

end

# How it gets used
wrapper = Wrapper.new(Widget.new)
wrapper.call
puts wrapper.result_saved_by_widget
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not that hard. A couple of points:

1. You probably want to call the original `save_result`. Otherwise, it's not much of a wrapper.
2. You need to use closure to capture current lexical context (meaning, memorize that we're in `WidgetWrapper`)

   ```
   class Widget
     def calculate
       save_result(3)
     end

     def save_result(arg)
       puts "original save_result: #{arg}"
     end
   end

   class WidgetWrapper

     attr_accessor :result_saved_by_widget, :widget

     def initialize(widget)
       @widget = widget

       wrapper = self # `self` can/will unpredictably change.


       @widget.define_singleton_method :save_result do |result|
         wrapper.result_saved_by_widget = result
         super(result)
       end
     end

     def call
       widget.calculate
     end

   end

   # How it gets used
   wrapper = WidgetWrapper.new(Widget.new)
   wrapper.call
   puts 'intercepted value'
   puts wrapper.result_saved_by_widget
   # >> original save_result: 3
   # >> intercepted value
   # >> 3
   ```

Comment: I think it would be better if you define a singleton method instead of using `class_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question but I think did something quite similar in the past, maybe the following lines can help you :

```
documents_to_wrap.each do |doc|
  doc.define_singleton_method(:method){override_code}
  tmp = doc.instance_variable_get(:@instance_var).
  doc.instance_variable_set(:@other_instance_var, tmp.do_something)
end
```